# positiveness of product of matrix

Tags: matrices, trace, positive-characteristic

If $A$ is a positive definite matrix, B is not sure but $tr(B)>0$ where $tr$ is trace, will $tr(AB)>0$ ? that is the trace of the product of those two matrices.
B is not a diagonal matrix or more specifically, $B=vec(D)*(c \otimes c)$ where c is any row vector and $D$ is positive definite. $vec$ is vectorization by column

Comment: Take $\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$. Can you find a $B$ such that the diagonal elements of $AB$ are zero?

Comment: I find a B that makes the diagonal elments of AB is zero..but tr(B)<0

Comment: Try $B=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -2 \\ -2 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Is $\otimes$ Kronecker product and * multiplication of matrix? If so, what is the dimension of $D$?

Comment: yes..$\otimes$ is kronecker product..and * is muliplication..so its column times row.  D is M by M matrix, so vec(D) is $M^2$  and c is M row vector, so $c \otimes c$ is $M^2$ row vector, and A is $M^2 \times M^2$ matrix

Comment: I started to feel tr(AB) can not be >0 for any vector c!!!..maybe for some vector c..but not all